# SequelizeDatabaseError after deplying nodejs app to heroku

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, heroku

I have an ecommerce app written in nodejs. I recently deploy my app to heroku..Here are the configurations:

> Development mode:

```
database: mysql
```

> Production Mode

```
database: postgresql add-on
```

Deploy done successfully and I've run heroku run bash command followed by sequelize -m commmand..After that I've done db:migrate and all the migrations were successfully done.but when I try to search the routes, I am getting an error on many routes.but there is a similarity on every routes.

for example: Here is the response I am getting on creating user routes.

```
  "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
  "parent": {
    "name": "error",
    "length": 105,
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "code": "42703",
    "position": "47",
    "file": "parse_relation.c",
    "line": "3294",
    "routine": "errorMissingColumn",
    "sql": "SELECT \"id\", \"username\", \"email\", \"password\", \"image\", \"createdAt\", \"updatedAt\" FROM \"Users\" AS \"User\" WHERE \"User\".\"email\" = 'developerstackbase@gmail.com' LIMIT 1;"
  },
  "original": {
    "name": "error",
    "length": 105,
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "code": "42703",
    "position": "47",
    "file": "parse_relation.c",
    "line": "3294",
    "routine": "errorMissingColumn",
    "sql": "SELECT \"id\", \"username\", \"email\", \"password\", \"image\", \"createdAt\", \"updatedAt\" FROM \"Users\" AS \"User\" WHERE \"User\".\"email\" = 'developerstackbase@gmail.com' LIMIT 1;"
  },
  "sql": "SELECT \"id\", \"username\", \"email\", \"password\", \"image\", \"createdAt\", \"updatedAt\" FROM \"Users\" AS \"User\" WHERE \"User\".\"email\" = 'developerstackbase@gmail.com' LIMIT 1;"
}
```

Comment: Why are you using MySQL locally and PostgreSQL in production? Those products aren't drop-in replacements for each other. I _strongly_ recommend using the same RDBMS everywhere.

Comment: Also, does this work locally with a brand new copy of your database, running all migrations from nothing? It looks like your migrations might not match your data model.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use same database for both environments and update if it is working on your local.